# From variable to text

Tags: sql, variables, view, procedure, declare

I have this

```
@mutation
@name
```

What I am trying to do is to make `@mutation` look for the name of a product(`name.products`) and then have `@name` take the name of the product in `@mutation` as text. So what I am trying to do is to get the name of a product in products table and use it to name a view later on.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[exec_view]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @mutation NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255) ;


SET @mutation = N'SELECT 
name 
FROM INSERTED

' ;


SET @test = N'@mutatation varchar' ;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @name = @mutation ;



EXEC (
'
CREATE VIEW @name
AS SELECT * 
FROM view_for_future_mutation
');

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @name sysname;

set @name = (select quotename(name) from inserted);

exec (N'create view ' + @name + N' as select * from view_for_future_mutation');
```